# Integrate Parse-SDK-JS to react antive app

Tags: javascript, react-native, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I tried to google some guides or tutorials and didn't found any. Is there any way to integrate into my react-native app a Parse SDK same as to android and iOS way? Because I tried to integrate Parse-SDK-JS and it didn't work now my app, crashing with error `Error: Unable to resolve module crypto from node_modules\parse\node_modules\crypto-js\core.js: crypto could not be found within the project.'`

my code:

parse.ts:

```js
 // In a React Native application
import Parse, { Error } from 'parse';
// On React Native >= 0.50 and Parse >= 1.11.0, set the Async
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export const initParse = () => {
  Parse.setAsyncStorage(AsyncStorage);
  Parse.initialize('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); //APP_ID
  Parse.serverURL = 'https://xxx.herokuapp.com/parse'; //HEROKU URI SERVER
};

export const testCreate = () => {
  const GameScore = Parse.Object.extend('GameScore');
  const gameScore = new GameScore();

  gameScore.set('score', 1337);
  gameScore.set('playerName', 'Sean Plott');
  gameScore.set('cheatMode', false);

  gameScore.save().then(
    (gameScore: any) => {
      // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
      alert('New object created with objectId: ' + gameScore.id);
    },
    (error: Error) => {
      // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
      // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
      alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
    },
  );
};
```

index.js:

```js
/**
 * @format
 */

import {
    AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';
import {
    initParse
} from './src/library/parse/parse';
import App from './App';
import {
    name as appName
} from './app.json';

initParse();

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import Parse from `parse/react-native.js`. It should be something like this:

```js
import Parse, { Error } from 'parse/react-native.js';
```